# Exceptions thrown by Mono inside flatmap not being handled by Spring webflux reactive stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am working on reactive streams application using Spring webflux. I have a usecase where I do a webclient request to get some data and once I get the response data, I validate it and if the validation fails, I want to throw an exception which should be handled by the `main` reactive pipeline. I'm using webclient call within a flatmap to use the value in the next operator of my pipeline. I have something similar to the following code:

```
public class Example {
    public String getData(String name) {
        return Mono.just(name)
             .map(name -> name.toLowerCase())
             .flatMap(name -> 
                  // Webclient Request that returns a 
                  // Mono<String> for example
                 .doOnSuccess(Validator::validateData); // The webclient request is chained to this doOnSuccess
             )
             .doOnError(ex -> log.error("Got an error, {}", er))
             .onErrorMap(ex -> new AnotherCustomException(ex.getMessage()));
    }
}

public class Validator {
    public void validateData(String data) {
        if(data.length() < 5) throw new CustomException("Invalid data received."); // public CustomException extends RuntimeException {...}
    }
}
```

Currently this code isn't using the `doOnError()` & `onErrorMap()` operators and I'm directly receiving the `CustomException` stacktrace on my console. I believe the reason being the code inside `flatMap` itself is a publisher `Mono` so it should have its own `doOnError()`, `onErrorMap()` operators. How do I make this Webclient's response i.e., `Mono<String>` be able to use the `main` pipeline that's using the `WebClient`?

Comment: Start with a working example.

Comment: `doOnSuccess` is for side effects meaning, that it will fork of execution and return immediatly with the same Mono before it. Its for instance if you want to log something or do a webcall somewhere that is not interrupting the general flow. Its not the operator you want. Read the reactor api before asking here please.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```
SomeWebclientCall().flatMap(value -> {
    Validate.validate(value);
    return Mono.just(value);
});
```

This might look wierd and that is because writing void functions that either return `void` or an exception is wierd and should be avoided.

Such functions are ineffective (throwing exceptions are expensive and should not be a natural flow of the program) and hard to test.

Thats why validation functions usually returns booleans as in it passed validation yes or no, true or false. Not void or exception.

Functional programming does not like void functions, only pure functions.